# In what order should Justice League movies be watched?

Tags: dc, suggested-order, dc-animated-universe, justice-league, justice-league-unlimited

I've caught up with the Justice League and Justice League Unlimited TV Show. I intend to start watching the Justice League movies as well.

What is the suggest viewing order for the [Justice League animated movies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_Universe_Animated_Original_Movies)?

Comment: Are you inquiring about these movies? Because they are not in  continuity with DCAU. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_Universe_Animated_Original_Movies.  There are no JL movies in DCAU canon, only 4 Batman movies.

Comment: @Shisa Yes. Those movies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [same Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_Universe_Animated_Original_Movies#Continuities) that you mentioned also has the answer to this. Most of the films before the Justice League: The Flashpoint Paradox doesn't share any continuity. Only few do, which are:

**Superman/Batman**
This continuity is based on the Superman/Batman story line.

- Superman/Batman: Public Enemies
- Superman/Batman: Apocalypse

**Justice League**
This continuity is based on the JLA (comic book) story lines published in 2000.

- Justice League: Crisis on Two Earths
- Justice League: Doom

**Batman: Dark Knight Universe**
This continuity is based on Frank Miller's Batman (Dark Knight Universe).

- Batman: The Dark Knight Returns – Part 1
- Batman: The Dark Knight Returns – Part 2

**Justice League: The Flashpoint Paradox** also works individually, but the ending set up a new universe similar to the comics. The film came after it severed the continuity and was called **DC Animated Movie Universe**:

This shared universe is based on The New 52 continuity.

- Justice League: The Flashpoint Paradox( End credit scene)
- Justice League: War
- Son of Batman
- Justice League: Throne of Atlantis
- Batman vs. Robin
- Batman: Bad Blood
- Justice League vs. Teen Titans
- Justice League Dark
- Teen Titans: The Judas Contract
- Suicide Squad: Hell to Pay (upcoming)

**Justice League: Gods and Monsters** This universe takes place in an alternate universe and has no connection to any of the other films

- Justice League: Gods and Monsters Chronicles (web series)
- Justice League: Gods and Monsters

Second season for Justice League: Gods and Monsters Chronicles was in works but shelved for now:

[image]

The rest of the films mentioned in that Wikipedia link are standalone and can be watched in any order.

As you might already know, there are [five Batman animated films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_animated_universe#Films) in the DCAU. But they sever the continuity to DCAU and the order of the rest of the DCAU [shared here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/46692/6006).

Comment: Are these bulleted lists meant to be ordered lists? So I should watch the Gods and Monsters Chronicles before Gods and Monsters?

Comment: @anaranjada Yes bulletin order is also the preferable order to watch. But for Justice League: Gods and Monsters, Chronicles is just three small video which doesn't impact the film at all but just introduce you will the trinity (mostly about how they work).

Comment: Was that second season of _Gods and Monsters Chronicles_ canceled?

Comment: @MolagBal shelved for now

Comment: Wasn't *Crisis on Two Earths* supposed to explain the new watchtower (now with teleport) in *Justice League Unlimited* as well as how Diana suddenly got an invisible plane?

Comment: @BMWurm it was supposed to but then they dropped the plan in production and it's not canon to DCAU.

Comment: @SheldonCooper Thanks. That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to *Justice League: The Flashpoint Paradox*, these films were the only ones with shared continuity:

- *Superman/Batman: Public Enemies* is followed by *Superman/Batman: Apocalypse*
- *The Dark Knight Returns Parts 1 and 2*

The other films prior to *Justice League: The Flashpoint Paradox* can be watched in any order, as they don't share continuity.

*Justice League: The Flashpoint Paradox* is the start of them building some continuity into these films, based on adapting the comic book *Flashpoint* event and their *New 52* reboot.  Watch that one then *Justice League: War* as it continues the story.  The next film in this story hasn't been released yet, but will be *Justice League: Throne of Atlantis*.

You can watch *Son of Batman* and *Batman: Assault on Arkham* in any order as well, just note that movies released after *The Flashpoint Paradox* will sometimes be part of the *New 52* film continuity.  Also note that *Assault on Arkham* shares a universe with the *Batman Arkham* games, so if you are planning on playing those, you may want to hold off until you've played them.  Specifically the 3rd one, *Arkham Origins*, as the story follows it ([source](http://www.gameinformer.com/b/news/archive/2014/05/16/batman-arkham-assault.aspx)).

Comment: I've only seen it once, so I'm not saying you're wrong, but I don't remember feeling like Assault was related to the games. Where did you learn this?

Comment: @BrianWarshaw Check this page - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_based_on_DC_Comics - `Batman: Assault on Arkham` | Based on the universe of the Batman: Arkham video game franchise

Comment: @BrianWarshaw 5 minutes googling lead me to the source that I added to my post.

Comment: @Keen And less than a minute commenting on your answer led me to mine :-)

Comment: "Each one is in its own continuity, so there's no carry over in terms of setting or story."  That's actually wrong.  Justice League: Doom is a direct sequel to JL: Crisis on Two Earths.  Also, Batman/Superman: Public Enemies is a direct sequel to Superman: Doomsday, as is Batman/Superman: Apocalypse.

Comment: @Robert Got a link or some evidence that links *Doom* to *Crisis*?  I did some Wikipedia reading and saw the link between *Public Enemies* and *Apocalypse*, so I've corrected the answer there.

Comment: The opening montage of Doom shows references and scenes from Crisis on Two Earths.  Plus, there is mention of the finished JL Satellite by Bruce's dime, something he mentioned in Crisis.  My evidence may not be as accurate for the batman/superman movies though.  Also, you forgot to link superman: doomsday to the batman/superman movies

Comment: @Robert How is *Doomsday* a predecessor to the *Batman/Superman* films?

Comment: Both Batman and Superman mention Superman's death and funeral during the Superman: Doomsday movie.

Answer (score 0):

**I personally would watch JLFP after Throne of Atlantis just so that it makes a little more sense (apart from the credit scene).** **IGNORE**

I have changed my mind. I have decided it makes more sense to watch JLFP before TOA as long as you believe that when Barry arrives into the new timeline it is after the events of JLW.

This design changes could be explained by the timeline changes. The different Flash suits make more sense (as he may have not made the New 52 Styled suit yet).
Batman's suit is teen to have a blue colour to it. In Batman: Bad Blood, his suit gets lighter and gains the blue colour, which could be more evidence.

Comment: This seems like a partial answer and would also be improved to [edit] why it would make more sense.