# What Films and TV make up the Current DC Universe?

Tags: dc-extended-universe, dc-animated-universe, dc

Unlike Marvel who has a well defined and established shared universe, DC seems to differ on what material belongs to what universe. I know that Arrow, Flash, Supergirl, and Legends of Tomorrow have had crossovers and seem to have a shared universe. Additionally the recent Batman films and the Superman films have been shown to share a universe; as seen in Batman vs Superman. Other series and movies however are less cut and dry. Where do movies and tv series like Constantine, Smallville, Gotham and others fall, and what relation if any is there?

Comment: [This answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72260/in-what-order-should-justice-league-movies-be-watched/125178#125178) lists a few of the universes.

Comment: [this answers part of your question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/66792/5184)

Comment: You mean to sort every TV show ever exists or just currently running ? As Smallville completed  long back and has been self contained.

Comment: I am not referring to all films in the DC universe. Most of the older stuff was self contained or had a limited number of sequels. I am asking what Films and TV series in the DC universe have shared universe's. For the sake of a baseline let's say from Smallville on; since that time range seems to be where the universe's start to appear.

Comment: DC has a multiverse!

Comment: Patented Jack B. Nimble [blog plug](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/11/a-guide-to-the-dc-cinematic-multiverse/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to this is very long, long enough that [I wrote a blog post](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/11/a-guide-to-the-dc-cinematic-multiverse/) on the topic.

The summary is:

- There is a DC Extended Universe that includes *Man of Steel*, *Dawn of Justice*, and the upcoming DC movies like *Suicide Squad* and *Justice League*
- There is a TV universe called the "Arrowverse", which includes all of the shows airing on the CW - *Arrow*, *Flash*, *Legends of Tomorrow*, and *Supergirl*, as well as the cancelled *Constantine* and the CW Seed *Vixen*
- Everything else is its own universe. (Movie trilogies counting as a single "thing" for this purpose.)

Comment: With the slight and confusing caveat that within the Arrowverse, _Arrow_, _Flash_, and _Legends of Tomorrow_ are in a parallel universe from _Supergirl_. :-)

Comment: And DCAU, which a comment from the OP excluded as too old, but it’s mentioned in a tag on the question.

Comment: @PaulL technically 1/2 of *Flash* is in a parallel universe from the other 1/2 of *Flash*, so...